# $T\in\mathcal{B}(X)$ with $T^{2}=0\implies\sigma(T)=\{0\}$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ be open, and let $T$ be as in the title with $\sigma(T)\subset\Omega$ and $f\in H(\Omega)$.

We can define $f_{n}(\lambda)=\lambda^{n}$. Then $\Phi_{T}(f_{n})=T^{n}$. Thus we have that $\Phi_{T}(f_{2})=T^{2}=0$. Now, let $x\in X$, with $x\ne 0$, then $\Phi_{T}(f)x=f(\alpha)x$, for $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$; which implies that every eigenvector of $T$, with eigenvalue $\alpha$, is also an eigenvector of $\Phi_{T}(f)$, with eigenvalue $f(\alpha)$.

Note that $\Phi_{T}(f):=f(T)$.

I guess I would want to use the spectral mapping theorem from here, or am I even going about this in the right way? I feel that I've maybe overcomplicated things a tad.

Comment: You can have it with less machinery. Let $\lambda \neq 0$. Then what is $\lambda^{-2}(\lambda I + T) \cdot (\lambda I - T)$?

Comment: @DanielFischer It is $\lambda^{-2}(\lambda^{2}I-T^{2})$. Then, if $T^{2}=0$, this would in fact equal the identity operator, $I$. I am now thinking about what this tells us, exactly.

Comment: Aye. So can $\lambda \in \sigma(T)$?

Comment: @DanielFischer If $\lambda^{-2}(\lambda I+T)(\lambda I-T)=I$ then this would imply that $(\lambda I-T)$ must be invertible, so **no**. Thus we must have that $\lambda=0$ (since we started with the assumption that $\lambda\ne 0$). Is it really such a simple proof by contradiction?

Comment: Effectively, yes. One needs to at least say that it's a two-sided inverse of $\lambda I - T$, and to complete it, one must give an argument for $0 \in \sigma(T)$. The argument works with small modifications for a general nilpotent operator. Another way is to use the formula for the spectral radius, $\rho(T) = \inf \lVert T^n\rVert^{1/n}$. If $T$ is nilpotent, $\rho(T) = 0$ follows immediately.

Comment: The spectral mapping theorem also works. If $f(\lambda)=\lambda^2$, then $f(\sigma(T))=\sigma(f(T))=\sigma(T^2)=\{0\}$. So $\sigma(T)=\{0\}$.